# Can a transfer fail when the receiving account is out of resources?

Tags: cpu, staking, resources, telos

I have seen this twice now on our Telos project - an account that ran out of CPU / net / RAM - not entirely sure which - became impossible to send to from another account that was still OK.

It's as if a resource starved account might be thrown into a limbo

I thought that all CPU, net is paid for by the sending account but I've now had two instances where this happened.

Trying to understand how this is even possible, or if it was just a fluke (or two flukes...)

I tried to transfer our custom token to the starved account and it failed. Then I staked some TLOS for the starved account and the transfer worked.

Comment: Not familiar with TLOS, but for eos, you can

Comment: Yes telos is the same protocol as eos. Thanks for the info. Still don’t understand why.

Comment: It can happen in a Microfork.